# Django DRF: Schema for bulk creation api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to build my API in which supports bulk create/update.
In these cases, the api will accept a list of object like

```
[
    {"foo":"bar"},
    {"foo":"bar"}
]
```

The code I'm using to allow bulk apis is just a small modification to add option many=True for serializer if the data is a list. It's like:

```
class FooViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        many = isinstance(request.data, list)
        if many:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_bulk_create(serializer)
        else:
            ................
```

I'm using [drf_yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for api doc generation.
But the problem is the schema generated keep detecting my request body just the single model only. Is there any config to make DRF schema generator knows that it will accept a list type?

Here is the schema which DRF generated

```
{
  "post": {
    "operationId": "foos_create",
    "description": "",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "data",
        "in": "body",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
        }
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "201": {
        "description": "",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
        }
      }
    },
    "tags": [
      "foos"
    ]
  }
}
```

My expectation is the **schema** would be the **array** type of Foo **definition**

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean generate schema  and schema generator?

Comment: @RedCricket Sorry for making you confused. What I mean is the schemas which DRF generated for the API docs (I'm using Swagger)

Comment: Ah. Can you post a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: Hi @RedCricket, I updated my question with the swagger json schema has problem. Hope it would be useful.

Comment: sorry for all the questions I am still new to Django and DRF.  Are you using: https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this. As far as I know that DRF depends on the serializer to inspect and build schema. But the bulk checking logic is at the view action method so the inspector doesn't know that it should be array or single object. I think it is the limitation of DRF. Anyway, thank you for your time @RedCricket

Answer (score 3):

I know it very old post but I was facing a similar issue, and as a noob in DRF and python took a while to figure this stuff out.
I just had to add a simple decorator.
FYI I have used https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk for the bulk update.

```
@method_decorator(name='perform_bulk_create', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(
    request_body=ContactSerializer(many=True),
    operation_description="post list of contacts"
))
```